# Strange things in using importNode, namespace and appendChild in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, namespaces

I found that the xml after importNode will have a "default" prefix. After some experiments, I found some strange phenomena.
How to explain the results below:
Code here:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$xml = <<<XML                                                                                                                                  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                         
<A xmlns="xmlns://www.abc.com"><B/></A>                                                                                                        
XML;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$new_dom = new DOMDocument();
$new_root = $new_dom->createElement("root");
$new_node = $new_dom->importNode($dom->documentElement->childNodes->item(0), TRUE);

//order is important                                                                                                                           
$new_dom->appendChild($new_root);                         //1                                                                                  
$new_root->appendChild($new_node);                        //2                                                                                  
$new_node->removeAttributeNS("xmlns://www.abc.com", "");  //3                                                                                  
//                                                                                                                                             

echo $new_dom->saveXML()
?>

123
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><B/></root>

132,231,321,312
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><default:B/></root>

213
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:default="xmlns://www.abc.com"><default:B/></root>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're removing a namespace definition for a used namespace. Depending on the order of the calls different repairs/fallbacks are triggered. The expected way to remove/change a namespace is to traverse and recreate the nodes.

libxml does some optimization and fallback for namespace definitions. It can happen that it replaces a namespace alias if you do "strange" things and it can break the result. On trigger are attributes with a namespace. but without a prefix. Unlike elements, attributes inside a namespace must have a prefix. Here is an example that triggers the default namespace prefix:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->appendChild($document->createElementNS('urn:1', 'foo'));
// add attribute in namespace without prefix
$document->documentElement->setAttributeNS('urn:1', 'bar', 21);
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<foo xmlns="urn:1" xmlns:default="urn:1" default:bar="21"/>
```

Even if you use an prefix for the attribute, libxml recognizes that it is the same namespace as the default element namespace an tries to optimize:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->appendChild($document->createElementNS('urn:1', 'foo'));
// add attribute in element namespace with prefix
$document->documentElement->setAttributeNS('urn:1', 'b:bar', 21);
echo $document->saveXML();
```

My rule is to always use a prefix for namespaces if I need to add attributes inside that namespace.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->appendChild($document->createElementNS('urn:1', 'b:foo'));
$document->documentElement->setAttributeNS('urn:1', 'b:bar', 21);
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<b:foo xmlns:b="urn:1" b:bar="21"/>
```

`$new_node->removeAttributeNS("xmlns://www.abc.com", "");` is telling the DOM the remove an attribute inside the namespace `xmlns://www.abc.com` without a name. However `xmlns=""` is not an attribute, but a namespace definition. It uses the same syntax and can in some cases be modified using the attribute methods but libxml might add it again because a descendant or attribute node is inside the namespace and the definition is needed.

Looking at them as attributes `xmlns="..."` is not in any namespace and namespace definitions with a prefix like `xmlns:foo="..."` are inside the reserved namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`. *imho* The correct calls to remove namespace definitions would be:

```
// xmlns="..."
$node->removeAttributeNS(NULL, 'xmlns');
// xmlns:prefix="..." - broken in PHP or libxml?
$node->removeAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'prefix');
```

Example:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->appendChild($document->createElementNS('urn:1', 'b:foo'));
$document->documentElement->setAttributeNS(NULL, 'xmlns', 'urn:2');
$document->documentElement->setAttributeNS(
  'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:bar', 'urn:3'
);
echo $document->saveXML();
$document->documentElement->removeAttributeNS(NULL, 'xmlns');
echo $document->saveXML();
// for some reason that does not work
$document->documentElement->removeAttributeNS(
  'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'bar'
);
echo $document->saveXML();
// but this works - weird
$document->documentElement->removeAttributeNS('urn:3', 'bar');
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<b:foo xmlns:b="urn:1" xmlns:bar="urn:3" xmlns="urn:2"/> 
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<b:foo xmlns:b="urn:1" xmlns:bar="urn:3"/> 
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<b:foo xmlns:b="urn:1" xmlns:bar="urn:3"/> 
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<b:foo xmlns:b="urn:1"/>
```